# QStandardItemEditorCreator in PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to implement Qt's Color Editor Factory Example (http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/itemviews-coloreditorfactory.html) in PySide.

The problem I'm facing is that QStandardItemEditorCreator class is not in PySide, or I haven't been able to find it after searching the docs for a long time. The only reference to it in the PySide documentation can be found in the following page (http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QItemEditorCreatorBase.html), the relevant part being the following:

> QStandardItemEditorCreator is a convenience template class that can be used to register widgets without the need to subclass PySide.QtGui.QItemEditorCreatorBase .

Without any link to QStandardItemEditorCreator.

In short, how may I get QStandardItemEditorCreator's functionality in PySide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing QStandardItemEditorCreator in python. Here's my implementation:

```
class QStandardItemEditorCreator(QItemEditorCreatorBase):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        super(QStandardItemEditorCreator, self).__init__()
        self.propertyName = cls.staticMetaObject.userProperty().name()
        self.cls = cls

    def createWidget(self, parent):
        return self.cls(parent)

    def valuePropertyName(self):
        return self.propertyName
```

If anyone has a better answer I'll gladly choose yours over mine.